# Cant return an int array with my java method

Tags: java

Just trying to have a method generate an array filled with random numbers and return that array so I can use it elsewhere but i keep getting ".class expected" on the return statement and I dont know why.

```
 private static int[] generateArray(int vals)
 {

   int tArray[] = new int[vals];
   for(int i = 0; i < tArray.length; i++)
   {
       tArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
   }
   return tArray[];

 }
```

Comment: Remove the brackets from the return statement, `return tArray[];` becomes `return tArray;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to return `tArray` not `tArray[]`.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static int[] generateArray(int vals) {

   int[] tArray = new int[vals];
   for(int i = 0; i < vals; i++) {

       tArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
   }
   return tArray;

}
```

You declared the `int` array a little out of order and it'll just be `tArray`, not `tArray[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static int[] generateArray(int vals)
 {

   int tArray[] = new int[vals];
   for(int i = 0; i < tArray.length; i++)
   {
       tArray[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
   }
   return tArray;

 }
```

Comment: awesome, so that was super simple, now am i able to use the array i got from generateArray() in another method? if so... how?